# "if" shorthand with double ampersand

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ampersand, shorthand, double-ampersand

I have seen these lines code.

```
this.tween && this.tween.kill(),
this.tween = TweenMax.to(object, 1, {
  ...
})
```

Is that a shorthand for

```
if(this.tween){
  this.tween.kill();
}
this.tween = TweenMax.to(object, 1, {
  ...
})
```

thanks ;)

Comment: A couple of things to take away, be carefulll its `&&` and not `&`, `if` has the upper hand for readability and if you end up expanding into muliple statement block.

Comment: Don't compress developement code, just use `if` as it shows the intention clearly.

Comment: I agree with `&&` being less readable than an `if`. It's a sort of "sideways [Yo Yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem)". You would read the first part, see the && then see the action and you have to go back and read when the action is to be performed. It's because it's not clear when you begin reading the line that it would be a conditional. This is not idiomatic usage of JS unless you're doing an assignment. It does appear in PHP and I think Ruby and/or PERL when re you could have a line like `db.connect() OR die()` to terminate if a connection cannot be made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the two are equivalent in execution.

```js
function test(value) {
  console.log(value);
  
  value && console.log("\texecute using AND");
  if (value) console.log("\texecuted using if");
}

test(true);
test(false);
test("string");
test(""); //empty string
test(0);
test(null);
test(undefined);
test(1);
test({});
```

However, with that said, it's not idiomatic usage of JavaScript. So you probably shouldn't be using this construct as it can throw other developers off. Your example illustrates that well, a code that looks like

```js
function f (condition) {
  condition && one(),
  two();
}

function one() {
  console.log("one");
}

function two() {
  console.log("two")
}

f(false);
f(true);
```

This is indeed *effectively*

```
function f(condition) {
  if (condition) {
    one();
 }

  two();
}
```

So, `one()` would be executed some times, while `two` would always be executed. However, without knowing the precedence rules, it could seem like *both* `one()` and `two()` would be executed conditionally. This is an easy mistake to make and even easier if it's a complex conditions and logic

```
person.account.moneyAmount > 0 && creditor.getDebt(person).moneyOwed > 0 && person.account.moneyAmount > creditor.getDebt(person).moneyOwed  && (deductTaxes(payAndReturnAmount(person, creditor)), printStatement()), printHello()
```

This is only slightly exaggerated but it's entirely possible to end up in a similar situation. If your code is as simple as a single condition and a single action then you save 2 *bytes* from using an inline condition vs an `if` statement

```
condition && action()
if (condition) action()
                     ^^
"extra" characters __||
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

```
this.tween && this.tween.kill(),
this.tween = TweenMax.to(object, 1, {
  ...
})
```

if `this.tween` is truthy value in this statement, it is evaluated and stays there. So it becomes like this code.

```
this.tween,
this.tween = TweenMax.to(object, 1, {
  ...
})
```

Comment: So how does that not make it identical,  eg.  Have you an example were it would give a different result.

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice that unnecessary codes remain even if it generates the same result.

Comment: That makes it a bad practice, but the effect is still equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a short Hand for the above code. Here if this.tween is undefined, the code after "&&" won't be executed. After that the code following "," will be executed.
here are some examples:

```js
this.a= undefined;
this.b= 20;
this.a && this.b.toString(),   // if a is true then b will be executed and converted to string
  console.log(this.b); // if a is true the output will be a string but in this case, a is undefined and the string conversion didn't happen, the console returns an integer
```

```js
this.a = 10;
this.b=20
this.a && this.b.toString(),
  console.log(this.b); // this will return a string
  
if(this.a){ // if a is true be will be converted to string
this.b = parseInt(this.b);
}
this.a = this.b;  
console.log(this.a) // if a is true be will be converted back to integet and assigend to a
```

if the a is undefined

```js
// a is undefined then
this.a = undefined;
this.b=20
this.a && this.b.toString(),
  console.log(this.b); // this will return a integer
  
if(this.a){ // since a is undefined it will fail and conversion won't take place
this.b.toString();
}
this.a = this.b;  
console.log(this.a) // a integer is returned
```

Comment: `// this will return a string` no, it returns a number - `this.b.toString()` doesn't change `b` in place. It just returns the value which is not used, so it will be thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

If **"state"** is **"true"**, the right side value **"test"** of double ampersand is displayed in **Console**:

```js
let state = true // Here

function test() {
  return "test"
}

console.log(state && test()) // test
```

If **"state"** is **"false"**, the left side value **"false"** of double ampersand is displayed in **Console**:

```js
let state = false // Here

function test() {
  return "test"
}

console.log(state && test()) // false
```